# Substitution encryption

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to make a substitution encryption program in java, but I'm having trouble creating the code and I'm wondering if you have any tips. My idea was to make the alphabet into numbers and then compare it to the plainText and then make a new string to send back.

This is my code:

```
package ComputerSecurity;

public class Substitution {

    String str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    public String encrypt(int key, String plainText){
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i< plainText.length(); i++){
            int position = plainText.charAt(i);

            temp.append(str.charAt(plainText.indexOf(position)+key));
        }
        return temp.toString();
    }
}
```

`key=3` but it's sent in by the main method `plainText` is "hello world".

Comment: What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: "but it's sent in by the main method" - what?

Comment: @runDOSrun, what he mean is that the main method calls `Encrypt(3, "Hello world")`

Comment: Hah. Thanks for decrypting!

Comment: my problem is that i dont really know how im going to do it

Comment: What do you exactly mean with comparing it to the PlainText?

Comment: Is your expected result `KHOOR ZRUOG` ?

Comment: Do you actually want to implement a caesar cipher?

Comment: Keep in mind that whitespace is not included in your str variable, thus you will only encrypt "hello"

Comment: If every letter have a number like abc is 123 then i compare the PlainText hello world to se which number it become and then i add the key which is 3 so it becomes an easy encryption

Comment: yeah i have to add that later but the main problem is the encryption part

Comment: Okay so your expected result is `11, 8, 15, 15, 18 ...` right ?

Comment: yeah thats what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you try to implement a Caesar Cipher.

```
plainText.charAt(i)
```

returns the actual current character, not a position. You can use the character to find the position in the alphabet:

```
char c = plainText.charAt(i)
int aPos = str.indexOf(c);
```

Then you can move this position and get the encrypted letter, but you need to wrap around. This is usually done with a modulo operation:

```
int encPos = aPos;
if (key >= 0) {
    encPos = (aPos + key) % str.length();
} else {
    // the key may be bigger than the alphabet length
    encPos = (str.length() + ((key + aPos) % str.length())) % str.length();
}
char ec = str.indexOf(encPos);
```

For every char where `aPos` is -1, you can skip the encryption. If you do this, then you can also encrypt spaces and other non-alphabet characters.

The problem with your idea to return a "number string" is that you don't know where one character number ends and where the next one begins. So, if you want that, you will have to add delimiters and this bloats your ciphertext unnecessarily.

Comment: intresting i will test it

Comment: Note that this is also the decrypt function by passing a negative "key" into it. Also note that a caesar cipher is in no way secure. A good modern cipher is AES.

Comment: I know im going a course in computer security at the moment and i wished to make an easy encryption but im no good when it comes to programing XD

Answer (score 1):

There is 3 problems:

- You use `str`. It will limit the alphabet you can use. In your case uppercase H and W and the space between the 2 word will give the same output  since they're not in `str`.
- Also, if you try to encrypt xyz with a key > 3 you'll end up trying to get a char in a position that doesn't exist in `str`.
- Finally, if you don't use a separator in our ouput it will be realy difficult to differentiate some case like 'ak' and 'ka' since both will output '111' with a key of 0.

My suggestion would be tu use the `int` value of the `char`. You can get it with `plainText.charAt(i)`.
For "abc" it will return 97, 98 and 99 since the code for `a` is 97. If you substract 96, you'll get 1 for `a`, 2 for `b`...
You'll just have to add your key to it.

```
package ComputerSecurity;
public class Substitution {

    public String encrypt(int key, String plainText){
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i< plainText.length(); i++){
            int val = plainText.charAt(i) - 96;
            temp.append((val+key) + ";");
        }
        return temp.toString();
    }
```

`encrypt(3, "Hello World")` will output `-21,8,15,15,18,-61,26,18,21,15,7,`.
If you want to get `11,8,15,15,18,-61,26,18,21,15,7,` put the plainText `toLowerCase()`.